# What's the difference between nmap and arp?

Tags: nmap

From what I understand, please correct me if I'm wrong, nmap allows you to discover machines on a network, any network whereas arp only allows you to discover machines in your own local network. Is this thinking correct? So in other words, arp is a more limited version of nmap? If that's the case what's the point of splitting up the tools? I'm pretty sure I'm getting something completely wrong some understanding somewhere so if someone could correct me that would be great thanks :)

Comment: Nmap is a program that will allow you to discover open layer 4 TCP and UDP ports. ARP is a protocol that resolves layer 2 hardware address to layer 3 IP address. They are 2 separate things. 

I think your best bet is to learn some Networking Fundamentals to give yourself a better grounding about how things fit together. http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/network-fundamentals-study-guide.html

Answer (score 8):

Nmap is a program that will allow you to discover open layer 4 TCP and UDP ports. ARP is a protocol that resolves layer 2 hardware address to layer 3 IP address. They are 2 separate things.

I think your best bet is to learn some Networking Fundamentals to give yourself a better grounding about how things fit together.

[Network Fundamentals Study Guide](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/network-fundamentals-study-guide.html)